# Linux Twinview : copy window application to both screens

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, twinview

I use the SUN Presenter Openoffice Extension with a twinview Ubuntu laptop. it works well : I have the video-projector with my presentation and my laptop screen with the slides (and time...).
My problem is when I want to present a mono-screen application, like Firefox, gnome-terminal. It is displayed only on one monitor, which is not really efficient if you want to be interactive.

Is there a way to display these types of application on both display and to interact with both ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `xrandr` to list your displays (I have them named like `VGA1` and `LVDS1`; they will appear as `VGA1 connected ...` in `xrandr`'s output), and then make output the same on each of two displays:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --same-as LVDS1
```

Comment: I don't want all the display to be copied, but just the window application I want ! I want my default display to be twinview to use Openoffice